# persistance/shared storage in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistent-storage

Hi I am trying to write a code for persistent/shared preferences. I am successfully saving the data in persistence storage. But every time I start my app it takes me to the storage activity. I have two activities Main Activity and Second Activity. In main activity I am saving the data and second activity I show the stored data. What I want here is when data is stored for the first time it should directly move to second activity. I want to achieve something like watsapp  registration process, you enter your number and pin for the first time and it never asks for it until you uninstall app or manually clear data. how can I do so. Below is the code I have tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MSISDN and PIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        int id = settings.getInt("PREFS_NAME", 0);
        if (id > 0) {
            Intent second = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), seond.class);
            startActivity(second);
        }
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsaveprefs);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("MSISDN", name.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("PIN", email.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                Intent second = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), seond.class);
                startActivity(second);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and second activity I have

```
public class seond extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MSISDN and PIN";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        TextView tvname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        TextView tvemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uemail);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        tvname.setText(settings.getString("MSISDN", "Unknown"));
        tvemail.setText(settings.getString("PIN", "Email default"));
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting name pref. on which you are checking if condition

Comment: @nitesh goel  check edited question

Comment: where are you setting PREFS_NAME??

Comment: _learn to format your code_ and do not post unrelated code in your questions

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays here:

```
int id = settings.getInt("PREFS_NAME", 0);
```

You fetch the value of "PREFS_NAME" and then check if it's `> 0` but you never store a value for the key `PREFS_NAME`. I guess you want to use `PIN` or `MSISDN` here?

Comment: not sure what the mistake is? am trying but unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct way to do it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MSISDN and PIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        int id = settings.getInt("PREFS_NAME", 0);
        if (id > 0) {
            Intent second = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            startActivity(second);
        }
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsaveprefs);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("MSISDN", name.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("PIN", email.getText().toString());
                editors.putInt("PREFS_NAME", 1); // id = 1
                editor.commit();
                Intent second=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
                startActivity(second);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Second extends Activity { // classes begin with CAPITAL

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MSISDN and PIN";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        TextView tvname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        TextView tvemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uemail);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        tvname.setText(settings.getString("MSISDN", "Unknown"));
        tvemail.setText(settings.getString("PIN", "Email default"));
    }
}
```

Notice you did not set the id as said in other answers. Your coding style is bad by the way : NEVER start a class name with lower case letters and also why is `id` an int ? You use it as boolean. Why do you save an email in a preference called `PIN` and a name in a preference called `MSISDN`???